# Unsatisfied link error for libvirt

Tags: java, java-native-interface, qemu, libvirt

I am trying to connect kvm through java using the code present at

https://libvirt.org/java.html

When I try to connect i receive the below error

```
2016-04-23 21:18:17.960 ERROR 6359 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'virt': libvirt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory] with root cause

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'virt': libvirt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:166) ~[jna-3.3.0.jar!/:3.3.0 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:239) ~[jna-3.3.0.jar!/:3.3.0 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140) ~[jna-3.3.0.jar!/:3.3.0 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:393) ~[jna-3.3.0.jar!/:3.3.0
```

I have libvirt installed on ubuntu

```
 libvirtd --version
libvirtd (libvirt) 1.2.2
```

And my build.gradle is

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.libvirt:libvirt:0.5.1')
    compile('net.java.dev.jna:jna:3.3.0')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}
```

Has anyone faced similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

since you are on linux this exception is thrown when your  application   attempts to load a native library like `.so`.in this case JVM is looking in both the PATH environment variable and the java.library.path system property.
.to fix this exception you need to set path for that library u are trying to load. just like you set path for java.

Comment: Yes but this is for libvirt.so which is used for the managing KVM,hence i guess that option wont work